# multiple results when outputting

Tags: python, python-3.x

i know this is a simple question but i cant find out where im going wrong
,when im outputting my beautiful soup to csv i am getting the output 8 times, which is also the number of results from the HTML find - where am i multiplying my output by the number of results? the output for pack3_value is only the data i need once

```
pack3_rows = [] 
for row in pack_rows3:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    pack3_row = [] # - for output
    for cell in cells:
        pack3_value = cell.string
        pack3_row.append(cell.text)
        pack3_rows.append(pack3_row)
        print (pack3_value)

with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvfile: 
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(pack3_rows)
```

Comment: Having variables named `pack3_rows`, `pack3_row`, and `pack_rows3` is **very** confusing. Consider renaming some or all of them. Also, what _is_ `pack_rows3`?

Comment: The problem is probably because you're doing `pack3_rows.append()` inside your `for cell in cells` loop, but that isn't entirely clear.

Comment: @Chris pack_rows3 is pack_rows3 = packtable3.findChildren(['tr','td']) packtable3 is parsing an exsisting HTML string

Comment: Okay, but without the HTML this doesn't make much sense. Ideally you should be providing a [mcve]. Emphasis on "complete" and "verifiable".

Comment: @Chris the HTML is business sensitive so i cannot share it unfortunately otherwise i would

Comment: @NathanBaker You don't need to share the proprietary data, just the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only append to `pack3_rows` once per row, not for every cell.

```
pack3_rows = [] 
for row in pack_rows3:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    pack3_row = [] # - for output
    for cell in cells:
        pack3_value = cell.string
        pack3_row.append(cell.text)
        print (pack3_value)
    pack3_rows.append(pack3_row)
```

If the `print` is just for debugging, and not needed for the real application, you can use a list comprehension.

```
pack3_rows = [] 
for row in pack_rows3:
    cells = row.findChildren('td')
    pack3_rows.append([cell.text for cell in cells])
```